# Is the respiratory substrate oxidised?

Tags: cellular-respiration

> Cellular Respiration is a biochemical process in which food materials present in cell are **oxidised** slowly in presence of enzymes with the release of ATP and small amount of Heat.

I am not able to relate this to the process of Fermentation(more specifically Lactic acid formation)

> $$C_6H_{12}O_6 \rightarrow 2CH_3CHOHCOOH + 36kcal$$

The average oxidation number of C in $C_6H_{12}O_6$ is $0$ and the average oxidation number of C in $CH_3CHOHCOOH$ is $0$. So, C is not oxidised according to oxidation number concept. So, can we say that all types of cellular respiration involve oxidative breakdown of substrate?

Comment: In lactate fermentation, there is no _net_ oxidation or reduction: free energy is obtained from the "splitting of glucose" (glycolysis). But of course, there _is_ an oxidation  step (GAPdh that generates NADH) AND a reduction step (pyruvate reduction by LDH to 'regenerate' NAD(+)), where the 'carbon skeleton' that is oxidized in the GAPdh reaction is reduced in the LDH reaction (so do no net ox/red).